# Does anyone know specifically what are all the entities behind Ripple and who runs / owns them?

Tags: ripple

As far as I'm concerned, there are `Ripple Labs` and `Ripple Foundation`, but I couldn't find any good resource providing more details on each of them.

I was wondering what their business model is and how it works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may need @DavidSchwartz to answer your this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

The team behind Ripple can be found here
https://ripple.com/company/leadership/#brad

Team running Ripple Foundation can be seen here
https://www.rippelfoundation.org/about-us/from-the-president/

They have a couple of banks signed to work on replacing old SWIFT based transactions between banks. There was also interested in currency exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a "centralized" cryptocurrency (or at least considered to be such), they are the best source.  www.ripple.com is probably the best resource.